# Visual Basic 2013 String Replacement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I found this code that replaces a string in a text file.  But, I am trying to make it so that it replaces several strings in a text file.

```
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\windows\PrinterList2.txt", My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\windows\PrinterList.txt").Replace("IT", "ADM-IT"), False)
```

For example, I need it to replace "IT" with "ADM-IT" and "AR" with "ADM-AR" and possibly a hundred or so more.

How can I get it to loop to do them all?  Running this line of code over and over just overwrites the file with the last item for replacement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sabhiram has the right idea. A lot depends on the data structure for our replace strings. You will most likely need to find a way to delimit the strings so you don't accidentally replace a string. e.g. if you need to replace 'IT' and 'IT2' if you replace the 'IT' first 'IT2' maybe destroyed. If your target strings may not be unique over the file, and they are unique over a row/line you may want to iterate over the lines and run all the replaces against each line.

Answer (score 0):

`Replace` returns a `String`, so you can just chain as many more `Replace` calls as you like on the end.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Legacy String.Replace(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) signature in MSDN, it seems like you can specify how many occurrences of the sub-string you wish to replace.

What you also need to remember is that the Replace(..) function will return back a `string` which you can keep replacing on until you are done.

If you needed to Replace all of "X" for "Y" then in the `for loop` below add another loop to call `Replace(x, y)` until the currently replaced string matches the previous one (this is probably naive and not very efficient).

Here is some pseudo-code (Dont like VB all too much :():

```
// Build a look-up-table of junk to replace
replace = [["IT","ADM-IT"], ["AR","ADM-AR"], [...]];
string s = ReadAllText("path/to/file");

string previouS = s;
for pair in replace:
    s = s.Replace(pair[0], pair[1]);
    while(previous != s)
    {
        previous = s;
        s = s.Replace(pair[0], pair[1]);
    };

// Write file back to disk
WriteAllText("path/to/file", s);
```

Comment: Your link goes to the VB `Replace` method.  The legacy VB methods should not be used, they are there for backwards compatability.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the two strings to replace, then you could use something like this:

```
Imports System.IO

File.WriteAllText("C:\windows\PrinterList2.txt",
File.ReadAllText("C:\windows\PrinterList.txt").
    Replace("IT", "ADM-IT").
    Replace("AR", "ADM_AR"), False)
```

This wouldn't be very efficient if there more than just a few.  Another problem with this approach is that *every* occurrence of IT and AR will be replaced, even if they happen to be withing another word.  For example, the word "STAR" will become "STADM_AR" so consider whether or not this will be an issue for you.